# shapiro test with three variables in R

Tags: r

I've got a dataset like the following with variable 1 and 3 being between-subject factors and variable 2 a within-subject factor. When I run the order for the shapiro test I get an error:

```
Problem with `mutate()` input `data`.
x Must group by variables found in `.data`.
* Column `variable` is not found.
i Input `data` is `map(.data$data, .f, ...)`.
```

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ID Var_1 Var_2 Var_3 value  
1 B 1 O 1.6
1 B 1 F 2.6
2 A 1 O 3.2
2 A 1 F 1.1
3 B 1 O 5.6
3 B 1 F 2.2
4 C 1 O 2.3
4 C 1 F 3.5
5 D 2 F 1.1
5 D 2 O 2.2
6 B 2 O 1.7
6 B 2 F 2.4
7 A 2 F 2.1
7 A 2 O 2.3
8 D 2 O 2.1
8 D 2 F 5.5
")
df %>%
  group_by(Var_1, Var_2, Var_3) %>%
  shapiro_test(value)
```

Can somebody help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Where does the `shapiro_test` come from? That doesn't appear to be a base R function. Are you sure you are calling it correctly?

Answer (score 4):

Apparently `shapiro_test` (from the `rstatix` package) is doing something unusual under the hood that makes it not like the name "value" ...

If you rename the variable to `foo` it works:

```r
library(rstatix)
df %>% rename(foo="value") %>% shapiro_test(foo)
```

Your example as written doesn't work because the Shapiro test needs at least three points to run; hopefully you have more data in your real data set ...

```r
(df 
   %>% filter(Var_1!="C")   ## remove group with only 2 values
   %>% rename(foo="value") 
   %>% group_by(Var_1) 
   %>% shapiro_test(foo)
)
```

It would be a public service to file an issue about this "infelicity" at the [rstatix issues list](https://github.com/kassambara/rstatix/issues) ...

Unsolicited statistical advice: I would be very surprised if it actually made any sense to do Shapiro-Wilk tests on the subcategories of your data, e.g. see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless) ...